# как исправить Pushage: рекурсия на всех путях выполнения, функция вызовет переполнение стека?

Tags: c++

```
struct tree {
    int ticket_code;
    int numberofthings;
    string last_name;
    tree* left, * right;
};
    void deleteBinaryTree(tree*& root)
    {
        if (root == nullptr) {
            return;
        }
     
        deleteBinaryTree(root->left);
        deleteBinaryTree(root->right);
     
        delete root;
     
        root = nullptr;
    }
    void Pushage(tree** t, string last_name, int ticket_code, int numberofthings) {
        if ((*t) == NULL){
            (*t) = new tree;
            (*t)->last_name = last_name;
            (*t)->ticket_code = ticket_code;
            (*t)->numberofthings = numberofthings;
            (*t)->left = (*t)->right = NULL;
    }
        if (ticket_code > (*t)->ticket_code) {
            Pushage(&(*t)->right, last_name, ticket_code, numberofthings);
        }
        else {
            Pushage(&(*t)->left, last_name, ticket_code, numberofthings);
        }
    }
    void AgeTree(tree* firstTree, tree** newTree) {
        string last_name;
        int ticket_code;
        int numberofthings;
        if (firstTree) return;
        last_name = firstTree->last_name;
        ticket_code = firstTree->ticket_code;
        numberofthings = firstTree->numberofthings;
        Pushage(newTree, last_name, ticket_code, numberofthings);
        AgeTree(firstTree->left, newTree);
        AgeTree(firstTree->right, newTree);
    }
    int main()
    {
        int n;
        tree* root;
        tree* newTree = NULL;
        
        AgeTree(root, &newTree);
        deleteBinaryTree(root);
        if (root == nullptr) {
            cout << "Tree Successfully Deleted";
        }
        print2DUtil(newTree);
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрим, удаляя не имеющие отношения к вопросу строки:

```
    void Pushage(tree** t, string last_name, int ticket_code, int numberofthings) {
    if ((*t) == NULL){
    // Тут код, который return НЕ ВЫЗЫВАЕТ
    }
    // Значит, мы 100% доберемся сюда.

    if (ticket_code > (*t)->ticket_code) {  // Если это условие истинно...
        // рекурсивный вызов
        Pushage(&(*t)->right, last_name, ticket_code, numberofthings);
    }
    else {
        // Если ложно - все равно рекурсивный вызов
        Pushage(&(*t)->left, last_name, ticket_code, numberofthings);
    }
    // Третьего не дано
}
```

Итак, ваша функция не имеет ни одного `return`. Она *при любых аргументах* вызывает сама себя. А значит, она никогда не закончится. Ну разве что переполнит стек, но вряд ли это то завершение, которое вам нужно, нет?

Comment: а как тогда исправить?

Comment: Чтобы скомпилировалось или чтобы правильно работало? :) Вы ни слова не написали о том, что должна делать ваша программа, как и так далее. Может, именно такое поведение вам и надо? Откуда я знаю, как исправить? Вот представьте, вы спрашиваете "Как исправить 2*3=12?" Откуда я знаю, что вам надо? 2*6=12? 4*3=12? 2*3 != 12? :)

Comment: У меня такая задача: Пересыпать данные с первого дерева в другое дерево того же типа, только
организованного по первому числовым ключом (например., годом рождения) и
распечатать его (а первое дерево стереть).У меня организовано с помощью ключа ticket_code

Comment: Ладно, скажем прямо: вы всерьез рассчитываете, что кто-то перепишет за вас всю программу?...

Comment: сделал return но чего-то все равно не работает